# How to show a pandas diagramm with HTML

Tags: python, html, pandas, matplotlib

So I have my diagramm but how can I show this with HTML? I want to use Flask to show the HTML page which shows me my diagramm but how do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


con = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/test2.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from data4 limit 79;",con)


df.plot(x = 'zeit', y = 'temp', kind ='line')

plt.show()
```

Comment: There's a python library called <a href="https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/index.html">bokeh</a> which can render plots in HTML.

On <a href="https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html?highlight=datetime">plotting documentation</a> is a section called _Datetime Axes_. You will find your answer there.

I am sorry but I can't help more than this. @Simon

Comment: Thank you ! After some reading and testing I was able to create a diagramm. Very helpfull again @theompm